# Do any browsers support CSS4 language/direction selectors yet? RTL TTB

Tags: css, css-selectors, right-to-left

I know that [the working draft from the W3C is not finalised yet](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#linguistic-pseudos) (at the time of writing this) but a lot of non standardised CSS have often been implemented by vendors ahead of formalization.

I'm finding it hard to find resources on this, and wondered if anyone knew which (if any browsers) support language or text-direction based selectors yet?

For example:

```
p:dir(rtl){
   /* some rules for right-to-left languages */
}

p:lang(somelanguage){
   /* some rules for specific language */
}
```

Comment: Doesn't even seem to be on the radar of http://caniuse.com yet. My guess would be *No*. Thanks for pointing this out though, hadn't heard of it.

Comment: Yep, it's still in draft but I'm building an app framework and I'm bored of having to write separate stylesheets, font hacks & mixins for arabic/farsi/chinese and it's going to make life easier when I can do it all in a nice semantic place:-)

Comment: The Selectors 4 FPWD just appeared less than a year ago... it's still too early to call for implementations when the draft is still going through major changes. I remember once when there was a question asking if any browsers had implemented Selectors 4 yet, and it was asked just **2 months after the FPWD**.

Comment: Do you need `:dir(rtl)`? Using `[dir=rtl], [dir=rtl] *`, you would get good browser coverage. When elements with dir=rtl and dir=ltr are nested, things get more difficult, but I think you could still meet most of your needs using just CSS 2.1.

Comment: There is no CSS4. This is the "Level 4" selectors module.

Comment: `[dir=rtl]` and `[dir=ltr]` never select `<p dir="auto"></p>`

Comment: Work for `:dir()` in Chrome is tracked at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=576815.

Answer (score 9):

:lang() has good support (and has had it since some time back now) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:lang

:dir() (first time I see it) seems to be only supported in Gecko https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:dir

Comment: `:lang()` isn't new to sel4 - it has been around since CSS2 which is why it enjoys good browser support. I don't think any browser has implemented wildcard matching though, which is the enhancement it is receiving in sel4.